# Liferay message listener (message bus) classpath

Tags: spring, liferay, classloader

I have implemented a message listener in Liferay (CE 6.2.5 GA6) to asynchronously store created/updated DLFileEntries in external DMS (calling an external WS to store them).

I have created a JAR file containing interface to my WS class which is located in the lib/ext folder of tomcat.

I have a ServiceLocator class in this JAR file which is initialized in the Spring context of my webapp. The initialization of service locator seems to work just fine and I am able to access the service instances in other web applications. However, when I try to access the service locator services from MessageListener class, the instannces are null.

As I understand it, the MessageListener classes are instantiated using the spring-messaging.xml files through the web.xml portalContextConfigLocation context-param. I suspect that the thready in which the message listener runs has different classloader than my webapp. That's why I tried to print the classpath of thread in which the message listener runs. I was surprised that the classpath doesn't contain any JAR file from tomcat's lib/ext folder.

Is this intended or a bug? Did anybody run in similar issue?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Just curious, are you using tomcat bundle for GA6 or you downloaded this tomcat separately?

Comment: Hi, I use the Tomcat bundle

Answer (score 0):

I think I have found the solution. It seems like I just had to change the messaging-spring.xml context intialization from `portalContextConfigLocation` context param in web.xml to `contextConfigLocation` like this:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
    <param-value>/WEB-INF/spring-context/portlet-application-context.xml, /META-INF/messaging-spring.xml</param-value>
</context-param>
```

The message listener is than in the same classloader like the rest of my webapp.